# How to build a MxMxN Tensor fast?

Tags: matlab, performance, tensor

Consider the equation `f=Ax` with `dim(f)=M`, `dim(A)=(M,N)` and `dim(x)=N`. The derivative `df/dA` is a `MxMxN` tensor and is defined through `dfi/dA = [0^T ... x^T ... 0^T]^T,` with `i=1,...,M`, whereby the location of `x^T` is at the i-th row of `dfi/dA`.

How would you perform a fast build of that tensor given `x` and `dfdA = zeros(M,M,N)`? My current approach is a for-loop: `for i=1:M; dfdA(i,i,:) = x'; end`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805355/creating-a-diagonal-matrix-higher-dimension

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a diagonal matrix (higher dimension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805355/creating-a-diagonal-matrix-higher-dimension)

Comment: The duplicate that @Ander suggested seems indeed to be the same, except here the diagonal for each 2D “plane” is a constant. Do time your loop vs the `bsxfun` solution in the other question, the loop is likely not any slower, and might even be faster! Nothing wrong with loops in MATLAB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come up with another variant by using the kron product. I also compared two different objectives; the first one is dedicated to the case when we want the output dimension `[M x M x N]`, the second one when we want `[M x (M*N)]`. In both cases we variant with the for-loop outperforms the other ones.

```
clear all; close all; clc; rng(0);

M = 3;
N = 2;

A = rand(M,N);
x = rand(N,1);


objective = 2;  % [1]: dim(dfdA) = [M x M x N], [2]: dim(dfdA) = [M x (M*N)]
switch objective
    case 1
        tic;
        dfdA = zeros(M,M,N);
        for i = 1:M
            dfdA(i,i,:) = x';
        end
        toc;

        tic;
        dfdA = zeros(M,M,N);
        dfdA(bsxfun(@plus,(1:M+1:M*M)',(0:M^2:(N-1)*M^2))) = repmat(x',M,1);
        toc;

        tic;
        dfdA = kron(x',eye(M));
        dfdA = reshape(dfdA,M,M,N);
        toc;

    case 2
        tic;
        dfdA = zeros(M,M,N);
        for i = 1:M
            dfdA(i,i,:) = x';
        end
        dfdA = reshape(dfdA,M,M*N);
        toc;

        tic;
        dfdA = zeros(M,M,N);
        dfdA(bsxfun(@plus,(1:M+1:M*M)',(0:M^2:(N-1)*M^2))) = repmat(x',M,1);
        dfdA = reshape(dfdA,M,M*N);
        toc;

        tic;
        dfdA = kron(x',eye(M));
        toc;
end
```

Comment: Use `timeit` to measure the time for each variant.